# Implement a GenericRepository in SpringData JPA with Hibernate?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have more than 20 entitity classes. I just don't want to generate `JPA` Repository for each of them. Instead a generic repository needs to be implmented 
 for normal crud operations like `save()`, `findAll()`, `findOne()`.

For ex: -

```
@Entity
class Student{}

@Entity
class Teacher{}

public interface GenericRepository<T,Integer> extends JpaRepository{ }
```

Here `T` should hold any type of `Entity`.. like `Student` or `Teacher`.

Comment: A small correction                                                                                                                 public interface GenericRepository<T,Serializable> extends JpaRepository{ }

Comment: A `Repository` is a collection of domain objects of a single type (or instances of a single aggregate root, to be precise). Therefore, to expect a single `Repository` to provide access to more than one type of domain objects is, strictly speaking, against the design principles of the `Repository` pattern.